# Plotly renders in R Shiny Browser on my computer, but not my team members'

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am displaying a plotly graph in an R shiny dashboard and it works perfectly on my computer.  However, when one of my team members runs the application from their machine, they get a blank plotly graph with axis and legends.  All other graph types work on their machine.  Cannot figure out what's is wrong because they seem to have all the correct packages downloaded. We are both using R Studio on a PC.

```
output$homeplot = renderPlotly({

monthtotalcmi = ggplot(data = allcmitotal2, aes(x = DATE_TIME, fill = CMI)) 
monthtotalcmi2 = monthtotalcmi + geom_histogram()
monthtotalcmi2 = monthtotalcmi2 + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
monthtotalcmi2 = monthtotalcmi2 + scale_fill_manual(values = 
c("dodgerblue3", "mediumpurple3", "darkorange"))
monthtotalcmi3 = monthtotalcmi2 + labs(title = "Daily Collection by CMI", x 
= "Date", y = "Reports Collected")
monthtotalcmi3 = monthtotalcmi3 + theme(legend.position = "none")
ggplotly(monthtotalcmi3)
})
```

Comment: The graph uses ggplot and ggplotly

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Also, try restarting R, to make sure you dont have something in your environment that he does not. That's likely the issue if your packages are all the same.

Comment: Below is the code used for the plotly.  The dataframe allcmitotal2 consists of 3 variables: REPT_NUM (the unique variable for each row and is basically an ID number), CMI (denotes a category that the rept_num is in and what the stacked bar is colored by), and DATE_TIME (the time stamp that the report comes in).

Comment: Actually I added it in the question body above.